# Is there a way to provide `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` option for dbic-migration script?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I use [DBIx::Class::Migration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Migration)

I extract data from database with command:

```
${MIGRATION_CMD} --schema_class ${APP_NAMESPACE} --database ${DB_TYPE} -Ilib dump_all_sets
```

The database is utf8 aware, but dumped fixtures has '?????' in place of utf8 character:

```
$HASH1 = {
           id         => 125,
           last_name  => '?????',
         };
```

The module does not document how to tell `dbic-migration` script about utf8 database aware.

**Is there a way to provide `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` option for `dbic-migration` script?** Like I do that with connect:

```
App::Schema->connect( $DSN, $user, $password, {
    mysql_enable_utf8 => 1
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I found. [The section](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#parse_dsn) where described how DSN is parsed shows:

```
DBI->parse_dsn("dbi:MyDriver(RaiseError=>1):db=test;port=42")
```

Thus in my case I just setup `DBIC_MIGRATION_DSN`:

```
DBIC_MIGRATION_DSN='dbi:mysql(mysql_enable_utf8=>1):dbname=mydb;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306' dbic-migration ....
```